# pyodbc execute works but executemany did not work

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am trying to import Excel data to Teradata, I have more than 15000 rows.

When I use execute for testing 50 rows, it works well, but it's too slow to import over 15000 rows.

then I searched for hours, I used executemany, and there is no error raised up, but it didn't update the database as expected.

Am I missing something?

```
import pyodbc
import pandas

df=pd.read_excel(Srpath,sheet_name="Sheet1")

connection = pyodbc.connect(r"Driver={Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20};DBCNAME=TDPROD1;AUTHENTICATION=LDAP;UID=" + username + ";PWD=" + password)

cursor = connection.cursor()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.executemany(
        "INSERT INTO Table(Cal_yr_num, Cak_pd_num, Banner, Company_code, Document_Number, GL_Account, Text_Info, Cheque_No, General_Ledger_Amount, Profit_Center, Cost_Center, CoCode_ChqNo, Account_Name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?)",
        row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12])

connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

executemany did not work(adding to database)

Comment: "I couldn't even import 1 row" - What do you mean exactly by that? Were there raised any errors? If so, please add them to your post, properly formatted in a code block.

Comment: it didn't raise any errors, but the database wasn't updated as expected.